# Is there something equivalent to enhpath in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

In Python the third party enhpath.py library allows for something like this:

```
In [2]: path("/home/lowks/Documents").listdir()
Out[2]: 
[path('/home/lowks/Documents/5fc72638da7598b350733c5a51fce596.jpeg'),
 path('/home/lowks/Documents/Prop-API-01.pdf'),]
```

The File module in Elixir does something like this:

```
iex(1)> File.ls!("/home/lowks/Documents")
["5fc72638da7598b350733c5a51fce596.jpeg","Prop-API-01.pdf"]
```

This does not work so well for me as I want the absolute path like the one above, so I do something like:

```
iex(2)> File.ls!("/home/lowks/Documents") |> Enum.map(&Path.absname(&1))
["/home/lowks/5fc72638da7598b350733c5a51fce596.jpeg",
 "/home/lowks/dsr_excel_csv.sql"]
```

but from the output it can be seen that the absolute path is joined to the cwd working directory rather than the correct one "/home/lowks/Documents". This looks and behaves like the stock python library for processing paths in Python, my question is do they have something that behaves like third party Python path libraries ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me, your second version would work if you used [Path.expand/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/Path.html#expand/2) instead of `Path.absname/1`:

```
iex(1)> path = ...
iex(2)> File.ls!(path) |> Enum.map(&Path.expand(&1, path))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have searched and have not found any libs for this, so I took it upon myself to create one:

https://github.com/lowks/Radpath

Comment: Just linking to your own stuff is [not a good answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). A good answer that involves an off-site resource includes the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and references the following: _What is this thing you're talking about? Where do I install it? How do I install it? How do I use this thing to solve the **exact problem** I have in my question? Are you affiliated with this thing in any way, shape, or form?_ See: [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it like this:

```
def dir_files(dir_path) do
  File.ls!(dir_path) |> Enum.map(&Path.join(dir_path, &1))
end
```